# Using cfqueryparam with a ColdFusion HQL query

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, hql, cfquery

I am using a HQL query to get a bunch of state objects like so:

```
<cfquery name="LOCAL.qStates" dbtype="hql">
    from States where countryID = #ARGUMENTS.countryID#
    order by name asc
</cfquery>
```

This works fine. However, I was brought up well and I want to use `cfqueryparam`, ideally like so:

```
<cfquery name="LOCAL.qStates" dbtype="hql">
    from States 
    where countryID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.countryID#" />
    order by name asc
</cfquery>
```

But this throws an error:

```
[empty string] java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:353) at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:323) at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:98) at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager._executeHQL(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:822) at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.executeHQL(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:751) at ....
```

Anyone know how to get around this and use `cfqueryparam` with `cfquery` HQL queries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this.

My `States` object was setup like so:

```
  <cfcomponent output="false" persistent="true">

      <cfproperty name="stateID" type="numeric" fieldType="id" generator="identity" />
      <cfproperty name="name" type="string" />
      <cfproperty name="alphaCode" type="string" />


      <!--- Relationships --->
      <cfproperty name="country" type="array" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Countries" fkcolumn="countryID" lazy="true" />



  </cfcomponent>
```

When using the `<cfqueryparam>` tag Hibernate was perhaps trying to map the number I was passing in as an array and failing thus throwing an error.

If I remove the relationship from the property like so:

```
<cfproperty name="countryID" type="numeric" />
```

...then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Take off the Datatype, it's not required and hibernate probably does not understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Indirect answer: use bound parameters instead.

```
<cfset orderDetail = ORMExecuteQuery("from Orders where OrderID=:orderid and ProductID=:productid", {orderid=1, productid=901}, true)>
```

You'll have to still roll your own validation on the variables though.

Comment: I actually WANT to use `cfquery`. This answers means I am back to ysing `ORMExecuteQuery()` which is not what I want.

Comment: @ciaran - why do you want to use cfquery? are you treating orm as a sql abstraction layer? if so you are missing some/most of the power

Comment: @Antony: The main reason is that I don't have to do ugly string concatenation and can write multi-line statements that are readable! :)

Comment: @ciaran - try cfsavecontent to avoid string concatenation